# Rails if greater than 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started playing with rails, what's the best way to do the following: @events.x is an integer, if its value isn't > 0 it has to be hidden.

```
<div class="chartwell radar">
  <span style="color: #fff;">dx</span>
  <span style="color: #3498db"><%= @events.design %></span>
  <span style="color: #1abc9c"><%= @events.typography %></span>
  <span style="color: #2c3e50"><%= @events.code %></span>
  <span style="color: #f8ff08"><%= @events.art %></span>
  <span style="color: #fd79f2"><%= @events.lifestyle %></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @events points to my database, where "design", "typography", etc are stored as integers. If such integers has a value of 0, it has to be hidden in the application. Something like [if == 0 (hide this)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment you want to show the value only if the value of the integer is no 0. so you can use this example:

```
<span style="color: #3498db"><%= @events.design unless @events.design.to_i == 0 %></span>
```

Or if you want not to display the span too

```
<% unless @events.design.to_i == 0 %>
  <span style="color: #3498db"><%= @events.design %></span>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if you meant something different.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it is hidden", what is "it"?  The whole div above?  Something else?

If you wanted to conditionally show a div for @events.x, like @events.art for example, you could do

```
<% unless @events.art == 0 %>
  <span style="color: #f8ff08"><%= @events.art %></span>
<% end %>
```

doing this for all of them is a bit tedious and repetitive.  You could dry it up like this:

```
<div class="chartwell radar">
  <span style="color: #fff;">dx</span>
  <% 
  [["#3498db", "design"],
  ["#1abc9c", "typography"],
  ["#2c3e50", "code"],
  ["#f8ff08", "art"],
  ["#fd79f2", "lifestyle"]].each do |color, method| %>
    <% value = @events.send(method) %>
    <% unless value == 0 %>
      <span style="color: <%= color %>;"><%= value %></span>   
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```